# Echo form data without sending to server

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

I have a tiny form on a page where I ask for the users name, the form sends the data to name.php and echos back the users name for example "Hello Steven" Steven being the name entered into the form.

Now that the name has been echoed to that form, I would like to echo that same data again elsewhere on the page. This is where I've run into a wall.

I would rather not send the names entered into the form to a server or database, but simply keep them for a session and then lose them.

The issue now is echoing the form data multiple times on one page.

The code I am using right now for the tiny form is as follows:

```
<form role="form" id="inviteform3" class="form-inline" action="name.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" 
id="hello" autocomplete="off" style="margin-top:10px">
                            </div>
                            <center>
                            <span id="result"></span>
                            <button class="btn btn-brand btn-sm next-screen animated bounceInUp" 
id="go" style="margin-top:5px; display:none" href="#services" data-animation-delay=".5s">  
Let's Go!</button></center>

<button class="btn btn-block btn-brand btn-xs invitebtn3" id="casi" type="submit" 
style="margin-top:5px"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Submit</button>

</form>
```

My php form (name.php) is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>

Let's get started, <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

and my js code is:

```
<script>

$(document).on("ready", function(){
//Form action
$("#inviteform3").on("submit", function(event){
// Stop submit event
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: 'name.php',
    data:$('#inviteform3').serialize(), 
    success: function(response)  
    {
        $('#inviteform3').find('#result').html(response);
    }});
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to get a few things straight:

> I would rather not send the names entered into the form to a server or database, but simply keep them for a session and then lose them.

You **ARE** sending that data to the server, you have used jQuery and AJAX to `POST` your form to name.php (php works on the server) from which you receive the response and add it your page with the line:

```
$('#inviteform3').find('#result').html(response);
```

If you want to **KEEP** that data stored (for example in a session), you can use the PHP suggested by  Antony D'Andrea in `name.php`. When the browser is closed, the session is destroyed. Untill then you can use the session variable where ever you want.

> Now that the name has been echoed to that form, I would like to echo
>   that same data again elsewhere on the page. This is where I've run
>   into a wall.

You are `echo`ing the name in `name.php`, your AJAX call then retrieves the whole page (including the `html` and `body` tags) and adds it to `#result`. If you want to show the name mulitple times, just append it multiple times with the line above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#inviteform3").on("submit", function(event) {
    var name = $("form input['name']").val();

     // Here is the interesting part
     sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
}

// Get that name
var access_name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

$("#some_id").html(access_name); // Inserts the name where you want it.
```

sessionStorage is wiped every time the tab/window is closed.

Comment: So now I could just use <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> where I need and it should echo the submitted data in that session? @Aroll605

Comment: No. Put the data into those areas with javascript `sessionStorage.getItem("name")`. That data is stored locally, your PHP script has no access to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not understanding how to inject the code into my page to view the result. @Aroll605

Comment: `$("#some_id").html( sessionStorage.getItem("name") );`

Comment: For what you want, it is much easier to just use PHP than javascript. Otherwise you have to bother with all this DOM manipulation. There is no benefit doing this client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP instead of Javascript.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

The `$_SESSION` variable is cleared when the browser is closed and is global so can be accessed anywhere. `session_start` has to be the very first thing you do though on line 1 of the first page that is run.

More info about sessions in PHP can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) and the about `$_SESSION` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

For example:

You are posting to name.php. So on line 1 of name.php do

```
  <?php session_start(); ?>
```

Then do

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
     }
?>
```

Then wherever you want to use it, just do `echo $_SESSION['name'];`

If you want to echo in other files. Then in line 1 of the other file do

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
```

Then:

```
<?php
     if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
     }
?>
```

The if statement is just there for checking, but you don't need it if you are confident it is set.

Comment: As I mentioned, @Antony D'Andrea, I am very new to php. I have managed to get as far as echoing the data once, but I am stuck, and I am not comprehending the suggestions I am getting. Any further help would be appreciated

Comment: I have tried to add an example. But I am not sure how much more clearer I can make it!

Comment: I have altered the php as you mentioned and injected <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> into my html file, but I am still not seeing the form data appear on submit. It only appears on that first request. My mistake is probably very silly. @Antony D'Andrea

Comment: Try (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) in the if statement

Comment: Still didn't show up. I altered the jquery and added $('#otherdiv').find('#result2').html(response);, and now the data is posting wherever I want it. Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but it worked......@Antony D'Andrea

Comment: Well at least it is now working. I could have probably helped more if I saw the entire codebase which is obviously impossible on SO! :)